# How can I filter column I will get with information _schemas.column in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, select

I have this request :

```
INSERT INTO colonnes ("colonnesName") SELECT "column_name" FROM information_schema.columns WHERE "table_name" = tableName;
```

but I would like only to get the columns which can be set NULL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of the `IS_NULLABLE` column for `YES` or `NO`:

```sql
INSERT INTO colonnes (colonnesName)
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'tableName' AND is_nullable = 'YES';  -- for nullable
```